# Github Copilot not working. Console "Output" window is empty

Tags: vscode-extensions, github-copilot

I have searched across Github issues and stack overflow, and whenever someone fails to get copilot to work (not suggesting anything) everyone tells you to update vscode, the extension, and open View > Output.

Well I have both vscode and copilot updated to the latest version, as well as being authenticated on Github. When I open Output, I can see the logs of every extension except Copilot. This is where I am stuck because I didn't read anyone mentioning what to do when there is NO output.

Comment: Hey, I'm having the same issue and I also can't find anything online.  Did you ever find a solution?

Comment: same issue, for me 'Github Copilot' is not showing up in dropdown 'Show output from:' , any solution? thanks

Answer (score 1):

Had the same problem.  Went nuclear and performed a complete uninstall of VS Code.  I also backed up my extensions and setting files before uninstalling.  After I reinstalled VS Code and connected to Github Copilot, the AI started to work.

Answer (score 0):

I believe I have the answer to this. If, like me, you had CoPilot installed, you've logged in, and co-pilot is either enabled for you or you are on the trial and things still don't seem to be working then try this.

In the bottom status bar of your vscode is the small bunny/bot looking co-piliot icon. Click it and it'll bring up some options. Simply select `Enable Completions` from this menu and you should now start to see Github Copilot output in the output of your vscode.